# Include additional directories to Makefile

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I'm a student and I'm currently working with the Infineon XMC4700 uC and have recently started to programm small "libraries" for for certain hardware components. For that reason, I createded a directory for each project and placed the corresponding files to it to test each component in a separate main.c file. As long as the .h and .c files are located in the same directory as the actual main.c file I know what I have to change in my Makefile.

However, for reasons of clarity and comprehensibility I'd like to place all headers in a "src" directory and all .c-files in a directory "inc".
For example, the current directory looks like this

```
~/EigeneProgramme/XMC4700/ShiftRegister
                               |_build
                               |_inc
                               |  |_ project.h
                               |_src
                               |  |_ project.c
                               |_main.c
                               |_Makefile
```

However, if I do this, the program does no longer compile. My first approach was to extend the VPATH variable to show the compiler the path to the required files.

The code below shows the declaration of certain variables in the currently used Makefile.

```js
CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi

CC = $(CROSS_COMPILE)-gcc
LD = $(CROSS_COMPILE)-gcc --specs=nosys.specs
AR = $(CROSS_COMPILE)-ar
AS = $(CROSS_COMPILE)-as
OC = $(CROSS_COMPILE)-objcopy
OD = $(CROSS_COMPILE)-objdump
SZ = $(CROSS_COMPILE)-size
ifeq ($(GDB_QUIET),true)
  DB = $(CROSS_COMPILE)-gdb -quiet
else
  DB = $(CROSS_COMPILE)-gdb
endif

BUILDDIR = build
LIB_BUILDDIR = lib_build
USB_LIBDIR = $(XMC_LIBDIR)/ThirdPartyLibraries/USBlib/USB

XMC_SERIES=4700
XMC_PACKAGE=F100
XMC_SIZE=2048

VPATH += $(XMC_LIBDIR)/CMSIS/DSP_Lib/Source/BasicMathFunctions:$(XMC_LIBDIR)/CMSIS/DSP_Lib/Source/CommonTables:$(XMC_LIBDIR)/CMSIS/DSP_Lib/Source/ComplexMathFunctions:$(XMC_LIBDIR)/CMSIS/DSP_Lib/Source/ControllerFunctions:$(XMC_LIBDIR)/CMSIS/DSP_Lib/Source/FastMathFunctions:$(XMC_LIBDIR)/CMSIS/DSP_Lib/Source/FilteringFunctions:$(XMC_LIBDIR)/CMSIS/DSP_Lib/Source/MatrixFunctions:$(XMC_LIBDIR)/CMSIS/DSP_Lib/Source/StatisticsFunctions:$(XMC_LIBDIR)/CMSIS/DSP_Lib/Source/SupportFunctions:$(XMC_LIBDIR)/CMSIS/DSP_Lib/Source/TransformFunctions:$(XMC_LIBDIR)/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC$(XMC_SERIES)_series/Source:$(XMC_LIBDIR)/CMSIS/RTOS/RTX/SRC:$(XMC_LIBDIR)/CMSIS/RTOS/RTX/SRC/ARM:$(XMC_LIBDIR)/CMSIS/RTOS/RTX/Templates:$(XMC_LIBDIR)/CMSIS/RTOS/RTX/UserCodeTemplates:$(XMC_LIBDIR)/ThirdPartyLibraries/Newlib:$(XMC_LIBDIR)/XMCLib/src:$(USB_LIBDIR)/Class/Common:$(USB_LIBDIR)/Class/Device:$(USB_LIBDIR)/Common:$(USB_LIBDIR)/Core:$(USB_LIBDIR)/Core/XMC4000

CFLAGS  = -I$(XMC_LIBDIR)/CMSIS/Include/
CFLAGS += -I$(XMC_LIBDIR)/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC$(XMC_SERIES)_series/Include/
CFLAGS += -I$(XMC_LIBDIR)/XMCLib/inc/
CFLAGS += -I$(USB_LIBDIR)
CFLAGS += -I$(USB_LIBDIR)/Class
CFLAGS += -I$(USB_LIBDIR)/Class/Common
CFLAGS += -I$(USB_LIBDIR)/Class/Device
CFLAGS += -I$(USB_LIBDIR)/Common
CFLAGS += -I$(USB_LIBDIR)/Core
CFLAGS += -I$(USB_LIBDIR)/Core/XMC4000
CFLAGS += -DXMC$(XMC_SERIES)_$(XMC_PACKAGE)x$(XMC_SIZE)
CFLAGS += -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mthumb
CFLAGS += -g3 -gdwarf-2
CFLAGS += -c
CFLAGS += -Wa,-adhlns="$@.lst"
SFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)
CFLAGS +=$(SCFLAGS)
SFLAGS += -Wall
CFLAGS += -Wall
CFLAGS += -ffunction-sections
SFLAGS += -x assembler-with-cpp
LFLAGS  = -T$(BUILDDIR)/$(LD_NAME).ld -nostartfiles
LFLAGS += -L$(XMC_LIBDIR)/CMSIS/Lib/GCC/
LFLAGS += -Wl,-Map,"$@.map"
LFLAGS += -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb
LFLAGS += -g3 -gdwarf-2

LIBSRCS += startup_XMC$(XMC_SERIES).c system_XMC$(XMC_SERIES).c
LIBSRCS += syscalls.c


OBJS = $(patsubst %.c,$(BUILDDIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))
LIBOBJS = $(patsubst %.c,$(LIB_BUILDDIR)/%.o,$(LIBSRCS))
```

Unfortunately, I'm not very experienced with Makefiles. For that reason, I'm struggling to adjust the Makefile to compile the program.

So could somebody provide a solution how to adujust the above shown snipped of my current Makefile to compile the program?

Best regards

RadbaldMeyer

Comment: When asking a question please always include (via cut and paste and formatting, not paraphrasing or screenshot) the exact command you typed and the output error messages you got.  In the case of problems compiling please also include the compiler invocation that caused the problem (this is printed out by make for example).

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `-I_inc` in the `CFLAGS`.

```
CFLAGS += -I_inc
```

`VPATH` is for another usage, mostly used to generate object files in a directory different from source files. In this case, in `_build`. When GNU Make try to build the binaries files, let's say `_build\project.o`, it will search for all the `project.c` in the VPATH list of directories. It will then compile the first `project.c` found and generate the corresponding `project.o`.

Comment: Thank your for the hint. If I add the CFLAG as suggested, I'm able to compile most of the required files. However, in the final step, the compiler fails to comile main.o. Thereby, it seems that the compiler does not know where to find the definition of the predefined functions in the header file.

Comment: build/main.o: In function `main':
/home/EigeneProgramme/XMC4700/ShiftRegister/main.c:16: undefined reference to `initialize_ShiftRegister_GPIO'
/home/EigeneProgramme/XMC4700/ShiftRegister/main.c:17: undefined reference to `initialize_ShiftRegister_CCU43'
/home/EigeneProgramme/XMC4700/ShiftRegister/main.c:18: undefined reference to `initialize_ShiftRegister_ISR'
/home/EigeneProgramme/XMC4700/ShiftRegister/main.c:19: undefined reference to `initialize_ShiftRegister'

Comment: This is not related to compilation. The compilation stage seems OK, the issue is at the linker stage: when the linker need to gather all the object files `.o` together to produce an executable file. The error you get means that the linker cannot find where are these functions implemented `initialize_ShiftRegister_GPIO` and `initialize_ShiftRegister`. These functions may be located in a C file, in this case you should add the C file in the `SRCS` variable.